# what is the best way to calculate the expected_value in assertEquals() method in jUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

I'm using the `assertEquals()` method in `jUnit` to test a certain value is equals or not to the actual value the code generates.

```
/*
  calculating the actual_value
*/
int expected_value = 1000; // rows of the set of files, manually calculated
assertEquals(expected_value, actual_value);
```

I'm wondering if I do it something like below will that be a problem, in case of standards and formalities.

```
/*
  calculating the actual_value
*/
int expected_value = getRelevantLinesOfFiles(set of files); // rows of the set of files
assertEquals(expected_value, actual_value);
```

since it's almost impossible to always find that kind of variable manually, I've written a method to read and calculate the relevant lines in those files.

My concern is that I'm using an out put of a method in `assertEquals` testing. But the `getRelevantLinesOfFiles()` method is not tested. If I'm going to test it, then again i have to manually read the files. So it's kinda same thing again and again.

Is that a good practice ? or what is the best way to do these kind of testing ?

Comment: Just have you files small enough to be able calculate result manually.

Comment: what if it is not possible ?

Comment: It is depends on what is a reason why it is impossible. It is restriction of tasting framework (then you need to fix it) or restriction of file format (it is hard to believe in this but technically possible)

Comment: normally because the file content  will be large. if we made it small then to that we need to change the process.

Comment: If you process do not allow you to test your product why don't you change it? Create small separate file for each test (or small group of tests)

Answer (score 4):

If those files are also the input that `actual_value` is calculated from, what you're doing is testing an alternative implementation vs the real one. That's valid but requires understanding things up front, e.g it's usually done with a very simple and easy-to-review test implementation compared with an optimized and more complicated 'production' implementation. If that's not the case you're doing something wrong.

If the files contain results that `actual_value` isn't calculated from then it should be ok, e.g if you have sets of inputs and matching sets of expected output.

Also, consider whether you can distill at least a few cases of trivial hard-coded input and hard-coded expected output, similar to your first example, not involving files. This may require allowing your interface to work with an abstraction that isn't a `File` in order to mock input, or to be able to inject an alternative file-reading mechanism in tests that actually serves mock test data.

EDIT: just to provide a concrete example of a great abstraction to use instead of `File` instances (or filenames, or whatever) consider using [okio](https://corner.squareup.com/2014/04/okio.html) and passing in a set of [Source](https://square.github.io/okio/okio/Source.html) instances.

**Real implementation**: given a list of `File` instances, create `Source` instances using [Okio.source(file)](https://square.github.io/okio/okio/Okio.html#source(java.io.File)).

**Tests**: pass a list of [Buffer](https://square.github.io/okio/okio/Buffer.html) instances containing whatever you want

```
Buffer b = new Buffer();
b.writeUtf8("whatever the hell I want in this file");
// can also write bytes or anything else

int actualValue = getRelevantLinesOfFiles(Arrays.asList(b));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. if the test files are generated only for test, i think you should carefully prepare these test files manually,  for example, 'file1' has 1 line, `file0` has 0 line, and 'fileX' has X lines, etc. no need prepare too much files, you can just consider some critical cases.
2. if these files are real data from production environment, then i suggest you write a method, like the `getRelevantLinesOfFiles` in your code, to count the line number of them. but firstly, you should test this method using the approach i mentioned above.

Answer (score -2):

It is always good practice to leave "Magic Numbers" (aka 1000) out of your code.  Like talex said, test the `getRelevantLivesOfFiles()` method on files small enough to count.  Then you can use it with confidence to test the other parts of your code.

Comment: Hard-coded explicit values in unit tests are what you usually want to do.

Comment: True, but the usage of EXPECTED_NUMBER_OF_LINES as a constant would be also acceptable here, depending on the question if it is important for the reader to know that there are 6 or 42 - or if the only thing the reader needs to know what this number means.